# Can't add colorbar to heatmap on a canvas using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, plot, heatmap

I'm trying to add a colour bar to a graph that I'm plotting in a GUI, however while the code works without the colorbar line of code, when I try to add a colorbar I get an error saying 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'. I've tried finding a solution but I haven't been able to figure out what I was doing wrong. Any help would really be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

a = np.array([2,-3,4,-2,1,2,4,3,5])
a = a.reshape(3,3)

class Graph:
    #Draws and return a placeholder for a graph
    #@param parent is the Tk.Frame parent obj
    #@param title is the (string) title for the graph
    def __init__(self, parent, title=''):
        #Initialise graph
        self.title = title
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(4,4))
        self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot()
        self.plot.set_title(self.title)
        self.plot.set_ylim(top=1)
        self.plot.set_xlim(right=255)
        self.plot.set_ylabel("Certainty")
        self.plot.set_xlabel("Pixel Value")

        #Draw
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=parent)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.draw()

        return

    def plotMaxDistHeat(self, maxDistMatrix):
        #Clear previous plot
        self.plot.clear()

        #Plot new results
        self.plot.set_title(self.title)

        self.plot.imshow(maxDistMatrix, cmap='coolwarm')
        self.fig.colorbar(self.plot)

        #Draw Graph
        self.canvas.draw()

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='red')
canvas.pack()
graph = Graph(canvas, title='Test Graph')

graph.plotMaxDistHeat(a)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Colorbar needs the object you colored, not the axes object.  I.e. do pc=imshow() and colorbar(pc)

Comment: @JodyKlymak this should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @JodyKlymak isn't that what I did?

Comment: `pc = self.plot.imshow(maxDistMatrix, cmap='coolwarm'); self.fig.colorbar(pc, ax=self.plot)`

Comment: @DizietAsahi Not sure its justified to make a whole answer out of something that is just a misread of the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
self.fig.colorbar(self.plot)
```

With

```
self.fig.colorbar(self.plot.imshow(maxDistMatrix, cmap='coolwarm'))
```